# Voltage of a complex pararell circuit

Tags: voltage, schematics

I'm trying to figure out the voltage of `DDR_VREF` below? I know it should be the half of `1.5V` i.e. `0.75V` but how? Can someone in detail explain each step to the arrival of the result of DDR_VREF?

I just know the basic calculation of electronic schemas. But I haven't seen a schema as below before. Thus, I don't know how to get the result of `DDR_VREF`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitors don't conduct when the supply is pure DC so ignore them. Next use ohms law to calculate current through R11 and R12. Hint Rtotal = R11+R12.

Next calculate the voltage across R12 given that current you just calculated.

Or, you can just simply look at it and notice that R11 and R12 are the same value hence the voltage at their midpoint is half of 1.5V

Answer (score 0):

When working with EE, there are two things to remember: superposition and symmetry. In this case, the symmetry is pretty clear, so DDR_VREF = 1V5_DDR/2.